# How do i connect facebook login to cordova application

Tags: facebook, cordova

Guys i want to connect with facebook in my application. i am using angularJS with cordova/phonegap. I have completed with all the code part and tested in chrome and works perfectly fine. Now i noticed that for it to run in android i need to add hash key to facebook developers site which i just did. after building it with phonegap build i noticed that my connect with facebook button doesnt launch the facebook login page which it does in webpage using chrome. Does it happen beacuse i am not using facebook plugin with cordova?

Comment: Please provide your console output when you think it should be displaying the facebook page.

Comment: @JBaczuk how do i get console output on my phone? O.O

Comment: iOS or Android?  For iOS disable private browsing, and enable web inspector, then use developer tools in Safari, the device should come up in the Developer menu.  For Android, you can use chrome://inspect/#devices but you'll need to enable debugging on the phone.

Comment: i am using android !! I will try as you said above and feedback the response. Thank you so much for such a fast reply :)

Comment: @JBaczuk console shows the error **"Failed to load resource file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=738518636191412&version=v2.0
"**

Comment: You can't access Facebook api from the file:// protocol. Can you provide your code where you try to access facebook?

Comment: @JBaczuk  `<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=738518636191412&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>`

Comment: @JBaczuk I guess i got my mistake. It works for web because i used web sdk for fb. For it to work with phonegap on my android i have to use plugin which uses Native sdk for FB. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Add https in front of the url you are using so that it doesn't default to the file:// protocol:

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id) 
{ 
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return; 
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id; 
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=738518636191412&version=v2.0"‌​;
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```